# Apache POI Select a cell multiple object

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I would like to provide a table, like in the picture.
In a column the days should be selected. They can see in the picture that I already the days as list, however, add I would like to choose in a cell 2 3 days together.
With me does not work now this. I can choose only one day in a cell.

[image]

My code looks thus.

```
     static void addDayChooserConstraint2Cell(Sheet sheet, int rowNumber,
        int columnNumber) {
    DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
    DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper
            .createExplicitListConstraint(daysOfWeek());
    CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, rowNumber,   columnNumber, columnNumber);
    DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint,
            addressList);
    validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
    sheet.addValidationData(validation);
}



static String[] daysOfWeek(){
    String[] daysOfWeek=new String[]{
            "MONDAY",
            "TUESDAY",
            "WEDNESDAY",
            "THURSDAY",
            "FRIDAY",
            "SATURDAY", 
            "SUNDAY"
    };
    return daysOfWeek;
}
```

you can see in picture, i can only one day selected. I want in a cell more then 1 day select
[image]

I have a visual BASIC code also gefindet.
Can i change this code as an Apache poi?

I wanted to make so
[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
//this might help u
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);
DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint .createExplicitListConstraint(new String[] { "Ann", "Ben", "Cam" });
DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList,dvConstraint);
dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
```